# overriding virtual function return type differs and is not covariant

Tags: c++, windows-7, mfc, 64-bit, build-error

I have ported my application from 32 bit to 64 bit platform and came across various build issues. I solved almost everything but I have come to an error I cannot figure out.

Could anyone advise on solving this error?

> "Error    61 error C2555: 'CICEVisionDlg::DoModal': overriding virtual
>   function return type differs and is not covariant from
>   'CDialog::DoModal'

Code for the `DoModal` override:

```
int CICEVisionDlg::DoModal() 
{ 
  int nRet; 
  m_bPopup = TRUE; 
  CEXTDLLState EXTDLLState(m_hResDllModule); 
  nRet = CDialog::DoModal(); 
  m_bPopup = FALSE; 
  return nRet; 
}
```

Comment: Can we see the `CICEVisionDlg::DoModal` function?

Comment: @moatazElmasry and @doub Ramsey Sure here is my code `code`int CICEVisionDlg::DoModal()
{
 int nRet;
 m_bPopup = TRUE;
 CEXTDLLState EXTDLLState(m_hResDllModule);
 nRet = CDialog::DoModal();
 m_bPopup = FALSE;
 return nRet;
}

Comment: Yupeee..Thank you guyz for the tip.I just changed the return type from int to INT_PTR and it solved my issue...thanks a ton :)

Comment: @Techy: If you solved your problem by one of the answers below, please accept one of them by clicking the check-mark.

Comment: Can you explain how the error message could be improved to make the cause of the problem clearer? It seemed clear to me: The overriding virtual function has the wrong return type (and it is not blah blah blah). But the return type is right there as the first reason.

Answer (score 11):

Return value of `DoModal` is `INT_PTR`, which is simply `int` on 32 bit but `__int64` on 64 bit platform. Change the return value of the overriding function to `INT_PTR` and it will compile on both.

Answer (score 4):

When you override a virtual function, you must return a correct type, where "correct" depends on the return type from the base class.

"Correct" means either the exact same type, or else with pointer and reference return types only, a "more specific" type. If the function in the base class `Base` returns `X*`, then the derived class can return a different type `Y*` provided that `Y` is a derived class of `X`.

Your problem is that the override of the `DoModal` function in the derived class `CICEVisionDlg` doesn't match the return type of the function in `CDialog` that it is overriding. Whether it's *supposed* to be covariant or not depends on the return type -- if it's not supposed to be covariant anyway then you can ignore that, and the error means "your function returns the wrong type!"